# Separate basename from the full file path

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mosrcat(char *o, int tsize, ...) {
  register int cot = 0;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, tsize);
  char *t = va_arg(ap, char *);
  while(t != NULL) {
    while((*(o++) = *(t++)) != 0) {
      cot++;
      if(cot == tsize) {
        *(o) = 0;
        return cot;
      }
    }
    t = va_arg(ap, char *);
    o--;
  }
  va_end(ap);
  return cot;
}

int mofibasename(const char *file_addr, char *fbasename) {
  register int mo = mosrlen(file_addr) - 1;
  register int n = 1;
  if(*(file_addr+mo) == '/') {
    printf("F\n");
    mo--;
  }
  while(mo != 0) {
    if(*(file_addr+mo) == '/') break;
    mo--;
    n++;
  }
  return mosrcat(fbasename, n, file_addr, NULL);
}

int main(void) {
  char o[255];
  printf("%d:%s\n", mofibasename("/home/Joe/Skh/", o), o);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my code. mofibasename() is to separate the file basename from the full file path.

Ex. `/home/Joe/Downloads/x.pdf` -> `x.pdf`
Ex. `/etc/passwd` -> `passwd`

But the function didn't work. It outputs as `/home` (Input: `/home/Joe/Skh/`).

Do I have anywhere wrong? I have tried many time.

Comment: Why do you have `register` in your code?

Comment: What is `mosrlen`?

Answer (score 1):

You may be overthinking it a bit. If you just want to trim the path from the filename (without making it easy using `string.h` functions), all you need do is find the end of the string and work backwards until you find a `/` or the beginning, e.g.

```
char *trimpath (const char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return NULL;  /* validate input string  */
    const char *p = s;

    for (; *p; p++);             /* find null-terminator    */
    --p;                         /* reposition at last char */
    for (; p > s; p--)           /* find char after '/'     */
        if (*(p - 1) == '/')
            break;

    return (char *)p;
}
```

The function simply returns a pointer to the beginning of the filename withing the total string. A short working example that takes the `/path/filename.ext` combination as the first arguments (or it uses its own default example name if no argument is given):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *trimpath (const char *s);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    const char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "/some/path/to/a/file.txt";

    printf ("\n full path : %s\n filename  : %s\n", path, trimpath (path));

    return 0;
}

char *trimpath (const char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return NULL;  /* validate input string  */
    const char *p = s;

    for (; *p; p++);             /* find null-terminator    */
    --p;                         /* reposition at last char */
    for (; p > s; p--)           /* find char after '/'     */
        if (*(p - 1) == '/')
            break;

    return (char *)p;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/trimpath

 full path : /some/path/to/a/file.txt
 filename  : file.txt
```

Using `string.h`, you can shorten the function to something like:

```
char *trimpath (const char *s)
{
    if (!s) return NULL;
    char *p = strrchr (s, '/');
    return p ? p + 1 : s;
}
```

Look them both over, and any other answers, and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
return mosrcat(fbasename, n, file_addr, NULL);
```

At this point `n` is 1 + the number of characters in the basename. You're copying `n` characters from the *beginning* of `file_addr`.

It sounds like what you want to do instead is start `n` from `0`, not `1`, and copy from the last slash in `file_addr` onwards:

```
return mosrcat(fbasename, n, file_addr+mo+1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OS supports POSIX, POSIX provides the [`basename()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) that does exactly what you want:

> **NAME**
>
> basename - return the last component of a pathname
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> [XSI] [Option Start] #include <libgen.h>
>
> char *basename(char *path); [Option End]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The *basename()* function shall take the pathname pointed to by path
>   and return a pointer to the final component of the pathname, **deleting
>   any trailing '/' characters.**
>
> ...

Note the bolded portion - POSIX `basename()` can modify its argument.

Also, be careful using `basename()` on Linux - Linux provides *two* `basename()` functions that have different semantics.  Per the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Warning: there are two different functions basename() - see below.
>
> ...

Read that man page before using `basename()` on Linux.